# use result of sql select in if else

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to construct a query where I check the number of rows returned from a sql select. For example, I want to check that if the number of rows returned from a query are greater than 3, then do something else do nothing

```
if @@rowcount(select clientId from Clients group by clientId) > 3
   PRINT 'WARNING'
```

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to do it all inside a query or are you using t-sql ?

Comment: Inside a query..want to set up a stored procedure

Comment: Well, in a Stored Procedure you can use T-SQL. As in **select [at]count = count(*) from table where condition** and then use the value of [at]count anywhere in your SP. If within a query, you have to do something like I said in my answer. You can put the **case** in the **select** or the **where**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

[EDITED]

```
DECLARE @Cnt AS INT
select @Cnt = COUNT(clientId) from Clients group by clientId
if @Cnt > 3
PRINT 'WARNING'
```

Comment: This returns the data, whether there is 1 client or 100,000 clients. Not sure that is desired.

Comment: I changed from @@ROWCOUNT TO variable. Both my logic should work. This will show WARNING, if the client count is greater than 3 only.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
case
    when (select count(*) from table where condition) > 3 Then
    else
end
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @Count INT = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ClientId) FROM Clients);

IF @Count > 3
    PRINT 'WARNING';
```